# How can I hide (Gravity) form if already submitted by a registered user

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

Is it possble to check in wordpress if a specific user ID has already submitted a particular form (Gravity Form) and if so to hide the form and display a message. eg "YOU HAVE ALREADY COMPLETED THIS FORM"

Answer (score 0):

There's a post that goes a long way to addressing this.  Seems you need to drop down to the PHP to accomplish it.
http://aaronjerad.com/blog/check-if-user-submitted-gravity-form/